# Drupal's End of the Page Doesnt Show Up

Tags: drupal, browser, drupal-7, scroll

I was installing module in Drupal but drupal doesnt show up end of the page, even though how hard I scroll it. It only scrolls down a bit and then immediately stop at a particular point. I dont know if this issue is within Drupal or the browser. I tried accesing drupal in Mozilla  Firefox and Google Chrome, but same problem occurs.I also tried browsing other web site but it seems like the problem only occurs in Drupal. Below is an image that shows the problem:

[image]

How will I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After installing module please clear the cache and after that please check it's work properly or not. You can also use “Module Filter” module to find module on the page.